# One Input OTP with characters splitted with squares

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to create OTP with one Input only. Which each character will be in a rectangle ( square ) and in the middle will be splitted with a line separator.

I didnt went with multiple inputs to try to exclude as much JS as i can. So would like to stick with  one Input only

This is how far i have come:

```css
:root {
    --otp-digits: 6;
    --otp-ls: 2ch;
    --otp-bgsz: calc(var(--otp-ls) + 1ch);
}

:where([autocomplete="one-time-code"]) {
    all: unset;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='60'%3E%3Crect width='40' height='60' style='fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:%23B2B2B2' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: var(--otp-bgsz) 100%;
    padding-block: 20px;
    inline-size: calc(var(--otp-digits) * 2.85ch);
    letter-spacing: var(--otp-ls);
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

input {
  padding-left: 18px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" 
    autocomplete="one-time-code" 
    inputmode="numeric" 
    maxlength="6" 
    pattern="\d{6}"
    onkeyup="if(this.value.length == 6) this.blur()"
/>
```

What i need to achieve is this:

[image: OTP Input]